# Why is my event variable undefined on input?

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML:

`<input (input)="test(1, $event)">`

Typescript:

```
test(index: number, event?) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

I'm trying to see if the user hits their backspace key on the input, but I can't get any of the user input using the $event variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *I can't get any of the user input using the $event variable*: what does that mean? What are you doing precisely (post the code!), what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? If you want to know is backspace if pressed, then the event should be keypress or keydown, not input. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent

Comment: Why do you use (input) at input this makes no sense.
Try this instead. `(keydown.backspace)="($event)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use keydown / keypress/ keyup [Keyboardevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) to identify the user interaction with keyboard.

Angular event bindings respond to any DOM event. Example usage of keydown event:

```
  <input (keydown)="onKeydown($event)">

onKeydown(event) {
  console.log("event.key:" + event.key)
  if (event.key === "Backspace") {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Other option, Trigger the keydown event for specific key. In the following example, the event will trigger only if the `backspace` pressed.

```
<input (keydown.backspace)="onKeydownBackspace($event)">

onKeydownBackspace(event) {
  console.log("event.key:" + event.key)
}
```